# How to create new arrays of even, odd and large numbers from an array and print their values sequentially? - must be use callback function to do this

Tags: arrays, function, loops, if-statement, callback

My Inputted Array is

```
var userArray = [4, 7, 2, 8, 9, 10, 15, 5, 1, 6, 12]
```

My expected output is

```
evenArray = [4,2,8,10,6,12] 
oddArray = [7,9,15,5,1]
greaterNumbArray = [7,8,9,10,15,12]
```

Finally, All values between 3 arrays is- 4 2 8 10 6 12 7 9 15 5 1 7 8 9 10 15 12

**Task is**:

1. Find the even, odd, and numbers greater than 6 and make an even & odd number array
   differently, last make an array of numbers greater than 6.
2. Show the results of 3 arrays serially.
3. Show the values of even, odd and large numbers together consistently.

> The ***callback function*** must be used.

Here is my code:

```
function behindOperation_2(arrayValue_2){
  var allArray_2 = [
    evenArray_2 = [],
    oddArray_2 = [],
    greaterArray_2 = []
  ]
  for(var i = 0; i<arrayValue_2.length; i++){
    if (arrayValue_2[i] % 2 === 0){
      allArray_2[0].push(arrayValue_2[i])
    }
    if(arrayValue_2[i] % 2 === 1){
      allArray_2[1].push(arrayValue_2[i])
    }
    if(arrayValue_2[i] > 6){
      allArray_2[2].push(arrayValue_2[i])
    }
  }
  for(var a = 0; a < allArray_2.length; a++){
    for(var v = 0; v<allArray_2[a].length; v++){
     console.log (allArray_2[a][v])
    }
  }
}

function dataFinding (getArray, behindOperation){
  var behindResult = behindOperation(getArray)
  return behindResult
}

var newResult_2 = dataFinding(userArray, behindOperation_2)
console.log(newResult_2);
```

my output is: 4 2 8 10 6 12 7 9 15 5 1 7 8 9 10 15 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to format your console output / printing correctly**:

You current number output is correct:

**`4 2 8 10 6 12 7 9 15 5 1 7 8 9 10 15 12`:**

`4 2 8 10 6 12 //even`

`7 9 15 5 1 //odd`

`7 8 9 10 15 12 //large`

Comment: re-write correct code & correction my mistake.